How to print an emoji using Java in Windows Terminal?
There are 3 essential elements to the question:

Windows Terminal version 1.20.11381.0 on Windows 11.
Java (I'm on a pretty old version -- Java 21)
Emoji.

Trying it directly shows a question mark:

Trying to set an environment variable doesn't help:

I've also tried chcp 65001, setting the encoding to utf-8 in Java code, etc., none of these methods worked. I tried echo "" and it worked just fine, but I want to use this in Java.
I've done a huge amount of literature research with no useful results. Everyone claims they have solved the problem using a method that doesn't work for me.

Java 21 is not old. That is the latest LTS version.

Set your console app to use UTF-8 as its character encoding.

maybe Changing ansi and OEM code page in Windows or Is it possible to set "locale" of a Windows application to UTF-8?  ((works for me, same Terminal version, but Windows 10))

that particular emoticon U+1F972 does not show up correctly on my system, not even on the browser; others are OK: screenshot

You can try this:
System.console().writer().write("")


Although this seems to work in jshell, it doesn't work in my application...
